# SQLiteJDBC giving org.sqlite.MetaData.getImportedKeys not yet implemented error with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite, jdbc, sqlitejdbc

SQLiteJDBC was giving me the following exception when used with hibernate's "hbm2ddl.auto = update" setting:

```
org.sqlite.MetaData.getImportedKeys not yet implemented
```

Any solutions? I found one below, and am posting it here for my future reference, but anyone else have any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With some browsing, I found a guy had made a patch for it which is
visible here: http://www.sqlpower.ca/forum/posts/list/2258.page

I've since applied this patch to the latest version of MetaData.java on
github, and recompiled it into a .class file and copied it into the .jar using 7-zip and it now works nicely with Hibernate.

Here's the updated java file: http://snipt.org/NnH

Here's the first half of the MetaData.java file (done in halves because it's so big):

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2007 David Crawshaw <david@zentus.com>
 * 
 * Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any
 * purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
 * copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.
 * 
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES
 * WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
 * MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR
 * ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES
 * WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN
 * ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF
 * OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.
 */

package org.sqlite;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Hashtable;

class MetaData implements DatabaseMetaData
{
  private static String sqlQuote(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
      return "NULL";
    }
    int i, single = 0, dbl = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      if (str.charAt(i) == '\'') {
        single++;
      } else if (str.charAt(i) == '"') {
        dbl++;
      }
    }
    if (single == 0) {
      return "'" + str + "'";
    }
    if (dbl == 0) {
      return "\"" + str + "\"";
    }
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("'");
    for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      char c = str.charAt(i);
      if (c == '\'') {
        sb.append("''");
      } else {
        sb.append(c);
      }
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

    private Conn conn;
    private PreparedStatement
        getTables = null,
        getTableTypes = null,
        getTypeInfo = null,
        getCatalogs = null,
        getSchemas = null,
        getUDTs = null,
        getColumnsTblName = null,
        getSuperTypes = null,
        getSuperTables = null,
        getTablePrivileges = null,
        getExportedKeys = null,
        getProcedures = null,
        getProcedureColumns = null,
        getAttributes = null,
        getBestRowIdentifier = null,
        getVersionColumns = null,
        getColumnPrivileges = null,
        getIndexInfo = null;

    /** Used by PrepStmt to save generating a new statement every call. */
    private PreparedStatement getGeneratedKeys = null;

    MetaData(Conn conn) { this.conn = conn; }

    void checkOpen() throws SQLException {
        if (conn == null) throw new SQLException("connection closed"); }

    synchronized void close() throws SQLException {
        if (conn == null) return;

        try {
            if (getTables != null) getTables.close();
            if (getTableTypes != null) getTableTypes.close();
            if (getTypeInfo != null) getTypeInfo.close();
            if (getCatalogs != null) getCatalogs.close();
            if (getSchemas != null) getSchemas.close();
            if (getUDTs != null) getUDTs.close();
            if (getColumnsTblName != null) getColumnsTblName.close();
            if (getSuperTypes != null) getSuperTypes.close();
            if (getSuperTables != null) getSuperTables.close();
            if (getTablePrivileges != null) getTablePrivileges.close();
            if (getExportedKeys != null) getExportedKeys.close();
            if (getProcedures != null) getProcedures.close();
            if (getProcedureColumns != null) getProcedureColumns.close();
            if (getAttributes != null) getAttributes.close();
            if (getBestRowIdentifier != null) getBestRowIdentifier.close();
            if (getVersionColumns != null) getVersionColumns.close();
            if (getColumnPrivileges != null) getColumnPrivileges.close();
            if (getGeneratedKeys != null) getGeneratedKeys.close();

            getTables = null;
            getTableTypes = null;
            getTypeInfo = null;
            getCatalogs = null;
            getSchemas = null;
            getUDTs = null;
            getColumnsTblName = null;
            getSuperTypes = null;
            getSuperTables = null;
            getTablePrivileges = null;
            getExportedKeys = null;
            getProcedures = null;
            getProcedureColumns = null;
            getAttributes = null;
            getBestRowIdentifier = null;
            getVersionColumns = null;
            getColumnPrivileges = null;
            getGeneratedKeys = null;
        } finally {
            conn = null;
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() { return conn; }
    public int getDatabaseMajorVersion() { return 3; }
    public int getDatabaseMinorVersion() { return 0; }
    public int getDriverMajorVersion() { return 1; }
    public int getDriverMinorVersion() { return 1; }
    public int getJDBCMajorVersion() { return 2; }
    public int getJDBCMinorVersion() { return 1; }
    public int getDefaultTransactionIsolation()
        { return Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE; }
    public int getMaxBinaryLiteralLength() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxCatalogNameLength() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxCharLiteralLength() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxColumnNameLength() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxColumnsInGroupBy() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxColumnsInIndex() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxColumnsInOrderBy() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxColumnsInSelect() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxColumnsInTable() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxConnections() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxCursorNameLength() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxIndexLength() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxProcedureNameLength() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxRowSize() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxSchemaNameLength() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxStatementLength() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxStatements() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxTableNameLength() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxTablesInSelect() { return 0; }
    public int getMaxUserNameLength() { return 0; }
    public int getResultSetHoldability()
        { return ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT; }
    public int getSQLStateType() { return sqlStateSQL99; }

    public String getDatabaseProductName() { return "SQLite"; }
    public String getDatabaseProductVersion() throws SQLException {
        return conn.libversion();
    }
    public String getDriverName() { return "SQLiteJDBC"; }
    public String getDriverVersion() { return conn.getDriverVersion(); }
    public String getExtraNameCharacters() { return ""; }
    public String getCatalogSeparator() { return "."; }
    public String getCatalogTerm() { return "catalog"; }
    public String getSchemaTerm() { return "schema"; }
    public String getProcedureTerm() { return "not_implemented"; }
    public String getSearchStringEscape() { return null; }
    public String getIdentifierQuoteString() { return " "; }
    public String getSQLKeywords() { return ""; }
    public String getNumericFunctions() { return ""; }
    public String getStringFunctions() { return ""; }
    public String getSystemFunctions() { return ""; }
    public String getTimeDateFunctions() { return ""; }

    public String getURL() { return conn.url(); }
    public String getUserName() { return null; }

    public boolean allProceduresAreCallable() { return false; }
    public boolean allTablesAreSelectable() { return true; }
    public boolean dataDefinitionCausesTransactionCommit() { return false; }
    public boolean dataDefinitionIgnoredInTransactions() { return false; }
    public boolean doesMaxRowSizeIncludeBlobs() { return false; }
    public boolean deletesAreDetected(int type) { return false; }
    public boolean insertsAreDetected(int type) { return false; }
    public boolean isCatalogAtStart() { return true; }
    public boolean locatorsUpdateCopy() { return false; }
    public boolean nullPlusNonNullIsNull() { return true; }
    public boolean nullsAreSortedAtEnd() { return !nullsAreSortedAtStart(); }
    public boolean nullsAreSortedAtStart() { return true; }
    public boolean nullsAreSortedHigh() { return true; }
    public boolean nullsAreSortedLow() { return !nullsAreSortedHigh(); }
    public boolean othersDeletesAreVisible(int type) { return false; }
    public boolean othersInsertsAreVisible(int type) { return false; }
    public boolean othersUpdatesAreVisible(int type) { return false; }
    public boolean ownDeletesAreVisible(int type) { return false; }
    public boolean ownInsertsAreVisible(int type) { return false; }
    public boolean ownUpdatesAreVisible(int type) { return false; }
    public boolean storesLowerCaseIdentifiers() { return false; }
    public boolean storesLowerCaseQuotedIdentifiers() { return false; }
    public boolean storesMixedCaseIdentifiers() { return true; }
    public boolean storesMixedCaseQuotedIdentifiers() { return false; }
    public boolean storesUpperCaseIdentifiers() { return false; }
    public boolean storesUpperCaseQuotedIdentifiers() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsAlterTableWithAddColumn() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsAlterTableWithDropColumn() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsANSI92EntryLevelSQL() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsANSI92FullSQL() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsANSI92IntermediateSQL() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsBatchUpdates() { return true; }
    public boolean supportsCatalogsInDataManipulation() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsCatalogsInIndexDefinitions() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsCatalogsInPrivilegeDefinitions() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsCatalogsInProcedureCalls() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsCatalogsInTableDefinitions() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsColumnAliasing() { return true; }
    public boolean supportsConvert() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsConvert(int fromType, int toType) { return false; }
    public boolean supportsCorrelatedSubqueries() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsDataDefinitionAndDataManipulationTransactions()
        { return true; }
    public boolean supportsDataManipulationTransactionsOnly() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsDifferentTableCorrelationNames() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsExpressionsInOrderBy() { return true; }
    public boolean supportsMinimumSQLGrammar() { return true; }
    public boolean supportsCoreSQLGrammar() { return true; }
    public boolean supportsExtendedSQLGrammar() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsLimitedOuterJoins() { return true; }
    public boolean supportsFullOuterJoins() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsGetGeneratedKeys() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsGroupBy() { return true; }
    public boolean supportsGroupByBeyondSelect() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsGroupByUnrelated() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsIntegrityEnhancementFacility() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsLikeEscapeClause() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsMixedCaseIdentifiers() { return true; }
    public boolean supportsMixedCaseQuotedIdentifiers() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsMultipleOpenResults() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsMultipleResultSets() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsMultipleTransactions() { return true; }
    public boolean supportsNamedParameters() { return true; }
    public boolean supportsNonNullableColumns() { return true; }
    public boolean supportsOpenCursorsAcrossCommit() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsOpenCursorsAcrossRollback() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsOpenStatementsAcrossCommit() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsOpenStatementsAcrossRollback() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsOrderByUnrelated() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsOuterJoins() { return true; }
    public boolean supportsPositionedDelete() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsPositionedUpdate() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsResultSetConcurrency(int t, int c)
        { return t == ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY
              && c == ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY; }
    public boolean supportsResultSetHoldability(int h)
        { return h == ResultSet.CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT; }
    public boolean supportsResultSetType(int t)
        { return t == ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY; }
    public boolean supportsSavepoints() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsSchemasInDataManipulation() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsSchemasInIndexDefinitions() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsSchemasInPrivilegeDefinitions() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsSchemasInProcedureCalls() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsSchemasInTableDefinitions() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsSelectForUpdate() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsStatementPooling() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsStoredProcedures() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsSubqueriesInComparisons() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsSubqueriesInExists() { return true; } // TODO: check
    public boolean supportsSubqueriesInIns() { return true; } // TODO: check
    public boolean supportsSubqueriesInQuantifieds() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsTableCorrelationNames() { return false; }
    public boolean supportsTransactionIsolationLevel(int level)
        { return level == Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE; }
    public boolean supportsTransactions() { return true; }
    public boolean supportsUnion() { return true; }
    public boolean supportsUnionAll() { return true; }
    public boolean updatesAreDetected(int type) { return false; }
    public boolean usesLocalFilePerTable() { return false; }
    public boolean usesLocalFiles() { return true; }
    public boolean isReadOnly() throws SQLException
        { return conn.isReadOnly(); }

    public ResultSet getAttributes(String c, String s, String t, String a)
            throws SQLException {
        if (getAttributes == null) getAttributes = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select "
            + "null as TYPE_CAT, "
            + "null as TYPE_SCHEM, "
            + "null as TYPE_NAME, "
            + "null as ATTR_NAME, "
            + "null as DATA_TYPE, "
            + "null as ATTR_TYPE_NAME, "
            + "null as ATTR_SIZE, "
            + "null as DECIMAL_DIGITS, "
            + "null as NUM_PREC_RADIX, "
            + "null as NULLABLE, "
            + "null as REMARKS, "
            + "null as ATTR_DEF, "
            + "null as SQL_DATA_TYPE, "
            + "null as SQL_DATETIME_SUB, "
            + "null as CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH, "
            + "null as ORDINAL_POSITION, "
            + "null as IS_NULLABLE, "
            + "null as SCOPE_CATALOG, "
            + "null as SCOPE_SCHEMA, "
            + "null as SCOPE_TABLE, "
            + "null as SOURCE_DATA_TYPE limit 0;");
        return getAttributes.executeQuery();
    }

    public ResultSet getBestRowIdentifier(String c, String s, String t,
            int scope, boolean n) throws SQLException {
        if (getBestRowIdentifier == null)
            getBestRowIdentifier = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select "
            + "null as SCOPE, "
            + "null as COLUMN_NAME, "
            + "null as DATA_TYPE, "
            + "null as TYPE_NAME, "
            + "null as COLUMN_SIZE, "
            + "null as BUFFER_LENGTH, "
            + "null as DECIMAL_DIGITS, "
            + "null as PSEUDO_COLUMN limit 0;");
        return getBestRowIdentifier.executeQuery();
    }

    public ResultSet getColumnPrivileges(String c, String s, String t,
                                         String colPat)
            throws SQLException {
        if (getColumnPrivileges == null)
            getColumnPrivileges = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select "
            + "null as TABLE_CAT, "
            + "null as TABLE_SCHEM, "
            + "null as TABLE_NAME, "
            + "null as COLUMN_NAME, "
            + "null as GRANTOR, "
            + "null as GRANTEE, "
            + "null as PRIVILEGE, "
            + "null as IS_GRANTABLE limit 0;");
        return getColumnPrivileges.executeQuery();
    }

    public ResultSet getColumns(String c, String s, String tbl, String colPat)
            throws SQLException {
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        String sql;

        checkOpen();

        if (getColumnsTblName == null)
            getColumnsTblName = conn.prepareStatement(
                "select tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name like ?;");

        // determine exact table name
        getColumnsTblName.setString(1, tbl);
        rs = getColumnsTblName.executeQuery();
        if (!rs.next())
            return rs;
        tbl = rs.getString(1);
        rs.close();

        sql = "select "
            + "null as TABLE_CAT, "
            + "null as TABLE_SCHEM, "
            + "'" + escape(tbl) + "' as TABLE_NAME, "
            + "cn as COLUMN_NAME, "
            + "ct as DATA_TYPE, "
            + "tn as TYPE_NAME, "
            + "2000000000 as COLUMN_SIZE, "
            + "2000000000 as BUFFER_LENGTH, "
            + "10   as DECIMAL_DIGITS, "
            + "10   as NUM_PREC_RADIX, "
            + "colnullable as NULLABLE, "
            + "null as REMARKS, "
            + "null as COLUMN_DEF, "
            + "0    as SQL_DATA_TYPE, "
            + "0    as SQL_DATETIME_SUB, "
            + "2000000000 as CHAR_OCTET_LENGTH, "
            + "ordpos as ORDINAL_POSITION, "
            + "(case colnullable when 0 then 'N' when 1 then 'Y' else '' end)"
            + "    as IS_NULLABLE, "
            + "null as SCOPE_CATLOG, "
            + "null as SCOPE_SCHEMA, "
            + "null as SCOPE_TABLE, "
            + "null as SOURCE_DATA_TYPE from (";

        // the command "pragma table_info('tablename')" does not embed
        // like a normal select statement so we must extract the information
        // and then build a resultset from unioned select statements
        rs = stat.executeQuery("pragma table_info ('"+escape(tbl)+"');");

        boolean colFound = false;
        for (int i=0; rs.next(); i++) {
            String colName = rs.getString(2);
            String colType = rs.getString(3);
            String colNotNull = rs.getString(4);

            int colNullable = 2;
            if (colNotNull != null) colNullable = colNotNull.equals("0") ? 1:0;
            if (colFound) sql += " union all ";
            colFound = true;

            colType = colType == null ? "TEXT" : colType.toUpperCase();
            int colJavaType = -1;
            if (colType == "INT" || colType == "INTEGER")
                colJavaType = Types.INTEGER;
            else if (colType == "TEXT")
                colJavaType = Types.VARCHAR;
            else if (colType == "FLOAT")
                colJavaType = Types.FLOAT;
            else
                colJavaType = Types.VARCHAR;

            sql += "select "
                + i + " as ordpos, "
                + colNullable + " as colnullable, '"
                + colJavaType + "' as ct, '"
                + escape(colName) + "' as cn, '"
                + escape(colType) + "' as tn";

            if (colPat != null)
                sql += " where upper(cn) like upper('" + escape(colPat) + "')";
        }
        sql += colFound ? ");" :
            "select null as ordpos, null as colnullable, "
            + "null as cn, null as tn) limit 0;";
        rs.close();

        return stat.executeQuery(sql);
    }
```

taData

Answer (score 0):

And here's the second half of the MetaData.java file:

```
    public ResultSet getCrossReference(String primaryCatalog,
      String primarySchema, String primaryTable, String foreignCatalog,
      String foreignSchema, String foreignTable)
            throws SQLException {

      StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        ResultSet rs;
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

        try {
          rs = stat.executeQuery("pragma foreign_key_list('"+escape(foreignTable)+"');");
        }
        catch(SQLException ex) {
          rs = null;
        }

        sql.append("select "
          + "null as PKTABLE_CAT, "
            + "null as PKTABLE_SCHEM, "
            + "PKTABLE_NAME, "
            + "PKCOLUMN_NAME, "
            + "null as FKTABLE_CAT, "
            + "null as FKTABLE_SCHEM, "
            + "'" + escape(foreignTable) + "' as FKTABLE_NAME, "
            + "FKCOLUMN_NAME, "
            + "KEY_SEQ, "
            + "UPDATE_RULE, "
            + "DELETE_RULE, "
            + "null as FK_NAME, "
            + "null as PK_NAME, "
            + "7 as DEFERRABILITY ");

        if (primaryTable == null)
          primaryTable = "";
        int i = 0;
      sql.append(" from ( ");
        if ( rs == null || !rs.next()) {
          sql.append("  select ");
            sql.append(" null AS PKTABLE_NAME,");
            sql.append(" null AS PKCOLUMN_NAME,");
            sql.append(" null AS FKCOLUMN_NAME,");
            sql.append(" null AS KEY_SEQ,");
            sql.append(" null AS UPDATE_RULE,");
            sql.append(" null AS DELETE_RULE ");
          sql.append(" ) limit 0");
        }
        else {
          do {
              String pktable = rs.getString("table");
              if (primaryTable.equalsIgnoreCase(pktable)) {
                continue;
              }

              String pkcolumn = rs.getString("to");
              String fkcolumn = rs.getString("from");
              String updateRule = "RESTRICT";
              String deleteRule = "RESTRICT";
              String seq = rs.getString("seq");

              updateRule = getDbRuleCode(updateRule);
              deleteRule = getDbRuleCode(deleteRule);

              if (fkcolumn == null || fkcolumn.length() == 0)
                fkcolumn = pkcolumn;

              if (i > 0) 
                sql.append(" union all ");

              sql.append("select ");
              sql.append(sqlQuote(pktable)+" AS PKTABLE_NAME,");
              sql.append(sqlQuote(pkcolumn)+" AS PKCOLUMN_NAME,");
              sql.append(sqlQuote(fkcolumn)+" AS FKCOLUMN_NAME,");
              sql.append(((Integer.valueOf(seq)).intValue() + 1)+" AS KEY_SEQ,");
              sql.append(updateRule+" AS UPDATE_RULE,");
              sql.append(deleteRule+" AS DELETE_RULE ");
              i++;
          } while( rs.next());
          sql.append(")");
        }
        System.out.println(sql.toString());

        return stat.executeQuery(sql.toString());
    }

  private String getDbRuleCode(String dbRule) {
    if (dbRule.equals("CASCADE"))
      dbRule = Integer.toString(DatabaseMetaData.importedKeyCascade);
    else
    if (dbRule.equals("SETNULL"))
      dbRule = Integer.toString(DatabaseMetaData.importedKeySetNull);
    else
      dbRule =Integer.toString(DatabaseMetaData.importedKeyRestrict);
    return dbRule;
  }

    public ResultSet getSchemas() throws SQLException {
        if (getSchemas == null) getSchemas = conn.prepareStatement("select "
                + "null as TABLE_SCHEM, "
                + "null as TABLE_CATALOG "
                + "limit 0;");
        getSchemas.clearParameters();
        return getSchemas.executeQuery();
    }

    public ResultSet getCatalogs() throws SQLException {
        if (getCatalogs == null) getCatalogs = conn.prepareStatement(
                "select null as TABLE_CAT limit 0;");
        getCatalogs.clearParameters();
        return getCatalogs.executeQuery();
    }

    public ResultSet getPrimaryKeys(String c, String s, String table)
            throws SQLException {
        String sql;
        ResultSet rs;
        Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

        rs = stat.executeQuery("pragma table_info('"+escape(table)+"');");

        sql = "select "
            + "null as TABLE_CAT, "
            + "null as TABLE_SCHEM, "
            + "'" + escape(table) + "' as TABLE_NAME, "
            + "cn as COLUMN_NAME, "
            + "0 as KEY_SEQ, "
            + "null as PK_NAME from (";

        int i;
        for (i=0; rs.next(); i++) {
            String colName = rs.getString(2);

            if (!rs.getBoolean(6)) { i--; continue; }
            if (i > 0) sql += " union all ";

            sql += "select '" + escape(colName) + "' as cn";
        }
        sql += i == 0 ? "select null as cn) limit 0;" : ");";
        rs.close();

        return stat.executeQuery(sql);
    }

    public ResultSet getExportedKeys(String c, String s, String t)
            throws SQLException {
        if (getExportedKeys == null) getExportedKeys = conn.prepareStatement(
                "select "
                + "null as PKTABLE_CAT, "
                + "null as PKTABLE_SCHEM, "
                + "null as PKTABLE_NAME, "
                + "null as PKCOLUMN_NAME, "
                + "null as FKTABLE_CAT, "
                + "null as FKTABLE_SCHEM, "
                + "null as FKTABLE_NAME, "
                + "null as FKCOLUMN_NAME, "
                + "null as KEY_SEQ, "
                + "null as UPDATE_RULE, "
                + "null as DELETE_RULE, "
                + "null as FK_NAME, "
                + "null as PK_NAME, "
                + "null as DEFERRABILITY limit 0;");
        return getExportedKeys.executeQuery();
    }

    public ResultSet getImportedKeys(String c, String s, String t)
        throws SQLException { 
      return getCrossReference(null,null,null,c,s,t);
    }
    public ResultSet getIndexInfo(String c, String s, String t,
                                  boolean u, boolean approximate) 
      throws SQLException {
      if (getIndexInfo == null) getIndexInfo =
        conn.prepareStatement(
                  "select "
            + "null as TABLE_CAT,"
            + "null as TABLE_SCHEM,"
            + "null as TABLE_NAME,"
            + "null as NON_UNIQUE,"
            + "null as INDEX_QUALIFIER,"
            + "null as INDEX_NAME,"
            + "null as TYPE,"
            + "null as ORDINAL_POSITION,"
            + "null as COLUMN_NAME,"
            + "null as ASC_OR_DESC,"
            + "null as CARDINALITY,"
            + "null as PAGES,"
            + "null as FILTER_CONDITION limit 0;");
        return getIndexInfo.executeQuery(); 
    }
    public ResultSet getProcedureColumns(String c, String s, String p,
                                         String colPat)
            throws SQLException {
        if (getProcedures == null) getProcedureColumns = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select "
            + "null as PROCEDURE_CAT, "
            + "null as PROCEDURE_SCHEM, "
            + "null as PROCEDURE_NAME, "
            + "null as COLUMN_NAME, "
            + "null as COLUMN_TYPE, "
            + "null as DATA_TYPE, "
            + "null as TYPE_NAME, "
            + "null as PRECISION, "
            + "null as LENGTH, "
            + "null as SCALE, "
            + "null as RADIX, "
            + "null as NULLABLE, "
            + "null as REMARKS limit 0;");
        return getProcedureColumns.executeQuery();

    }

    public ResultSet getProcedures(String c, String s, String p)
            throws SQLException {
        if (getProcedures == null) getProcedures = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select "
            + "null as PROCEDURE_CAT, "
            + "null as PROCEDURE_SCHEM, "
            + "null as PROCEDURE_NAME, "
            + "null as UNDEF1, "
            + "null as UNDEF2, "
            + "null as UNDEF3, "
            + "null as REMARKS, "
            + "null as PROCEDURE_TYPE limit 0;");
        return getProcedures.executeQuery();
    }

    public ResultSet getSuperTables(String c, String s, String t)
            throws SQLException {
        if (getSuperTables == null) getSuperTables = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select "
            + "null as TABLE_CAT, "
            + "null as TABLE_SCHEM, "
            + "null as TABLE_NAME, "
            + "null as SUPERTABLE_NAME limit 0;");
        return getSuperTables.executeQuery();
    }

    public ResultSet getSuperTypes(String c, String s, String t)
            throws SQLException {
        if (getSuperTypes == null) getSuperTypes = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select "
            + "null as TYPE_CAT, "
            + "null as TYPE_SCHEM, "
            + "null as TYPE_NAME, "
            + "null as SUPERTYPE_CAT, "
            + "null as SUPERTYPE_SCHEM, "
            + "null as SUPERTYPE_NAME limit 0;");
        return getSuperTypes.executeQuery();
    }

    public ResultSet getTablePrivileges(String c, String s, String t)
            throws SQLException {
        if (getTablePrivileges == null)
            getTablePrivileges = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select "
            + "null as TABLE_CAT, "
            + "null as TABLE_SCHEM, "
            + "null as TABLE_NAME, "
            + "null as GRANTOR, "
            + "null as GRANTEE, "
            + "null as PRIVILEGE, "
            + "null as IS_GRANTABLE limit 0;");
        return getTablePrivileges.executeQuery();
    }

    public synchronized ResultSet getTables(String c, String s,
            String t, String[] types) throws SQLException {
        checkOpen();

        t = (t == null || "".equals(t)) ? "%" : t.toUpperCase();

        String sql = "select"
                + " null as TABLE_CAT,"
                + " null as TABLE_SCHEM,"
                + " upper(name) as TABLE_NAME,"
                + " upper(type) as TABLE_TYPE,"
                + " null as REMARKS,"
                + " null as TYPE_CAT,"
                + " null as TYPE_SCHEM,"
                + " null as TYPE_NAME,"
                + " null as SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME,"
                + " null as REF_GENERATION"
                + " from (select name, type from sqlite_master union all"
                + "       select name, type from sqlite_temp_master)"
                + " where TABLE_NAME like '" + escape(t) + "'";

        if (types != null) {
            sql += " and TABLE_TYPE in (";
            for (int i=0; i < types.length; i++) {
                if (i > 0) sql += ", ";
                sql += "'" + types[i].toUpperCase() + "'";
            }
            sql += ")";
        }

        sql += ";";

        return conn.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
    }

    public ResultSet getTableTypes() throws SQLException {
        checkOpen();
        if (getTableTypes == null) getTableTypes = conn.prepareStatement(
                "select 'TABLE' as TABLE_TYPE"
                + " union select 'VIEW' as TABLE_TYPE;");
        getTableTypes.clearParameters();
        return getTableTypes.executeQuery();
    }

    public ResultSet getTypeInfo() throws SQLException {
        if (getTypeInfo == null) {
            getTypeInfo = conn.prepareStatement(
                  "select "
                + "tn as TYPE_NAME, "
                + "dt as DATA_TYPE, "
                + "0 as PRECISION, "
                + "null as LITERAL_PREFIX, "
                + "null as LITERAL_SUFFIX, "
                + "null as CREATE_PARAMS, "
                + typeNullable + " as NULLABLE, "
                + "1 as CASE_SENSITIVE, "
                + typeSearchable + " as SEARCHABLE, "
                + "0 as UNSIGNED_ATTRIBUTE, "
                + "0 as FIXED_PREC_SCALE, "
                + "0 as AUTO_INCREMENT, "
                + "null as LOCAL_TYPE_NAME, "
                + "0 as MINIMUM_SCALE, "
                + "0 as MAXIMUM_SCALE, "
                + "0 as SQL_DATA_TYPE, "
                + "0 as SQL_DATETIME_SUB, "
                + "10 as NUM_PREC_RADIX from ("
                + "    select 'BLOB' as tn, " + Types.BLOB + " as dt union"
                + "    select 'NULL' as tn, " + Types.NULL + " as dt union"
                + "    select 'REAL' as tn, " + Types.REAL+ " as dt union"
                + "    select 'TEXT' as tn, " + Types.VARCHAR + " as dt union"
                + "    select 'INTEGER' as tn, "+ Types.INTEGER +" as dt"
                + ") order by TYPE_NAME;"
            );
        }

        getTypeInfo.clearParameters();
        return getTypeInfo.executeQuery();
    }

    public ResultSet getUDTs(String c, String s, String t, int[] types)
            throws SQLException {
        if (getUDTs == null) getUDTs = conn.prepareStatement("select "
                + "null as TYPE_CAT, "
                + "null as TYPE_SCHEM, "
                + "null as TYPE_NAME, "
                + "null as CLASS_NAME, "
                + "null as DATA_TYPE, "
                + "null as REMARKS, "
                + "null as BASE_TYPE "
                + "limit 0;");

        getUDTs.clearParameters();
        return getUDTs.executeQuery();
    }
    public ResultSet getVersionColumns(String c, String s, String t)
            throws SQLException {
        if (getVersionColumns == null)
            getVersionColumns = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select "
            + "null as SCOPE, "
            + "null as COLUMN_NAME, "
            + "null as DATA_TYPE, "
            + "null as TYPE_NAME, "
            + "null as COLUMN_SIZE, "
            + "null as BUFFER_LENGTH, "
            + "null as DECIMAL_DIGITS, "
            + "null as PSEUDO_COLUMN limit 0;");
        return getVersionColumns.executeQuery();
    }

    ResultSet getGeneratedKeys() throws SQLException {
        if (getGeneratedKeys == null) getGeneratedKeys = conn.prepareStatement(
            "select last_insert_rowid();");
        return getGeneratedKeys.executeQuery();
    }

    /** Replace all instances of ' with '' */
    private String escape(final String val) {
        // TODO: this function is ugly, pass this work off to SQLite, then we
        //       don't have to worry about Unicode 4, other characters needing
        //       escaping, etc.
        int len = val.length();
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(len);
        for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
            if (val.charAt(i) == '\'') buf.append('\'');
            buf.append(val.charAt(i));
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }

    public Struct createStruct(String t, Object[] attr) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLException("Not yet implemented by SQLite JDBC driver"); }
    public ResultSet getFunctionColumns(String a, String b, String c,
                String d) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLException("Not yet implemented by SQLite JDBC driver"); }


    public ResultSet getFunctions(String a, String b, String c) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLException("Not yet implemented by SQLite JDBC driver"); }        
    public ResultSet getClientInfoProperties()  throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLException("Not yet implemented by SQLite JDBC driver"); }        
    public boolean autoCommitFailureClosesAllResultSets() throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLException("Not yet implemented by SQLite JDBC driver"); }        
    public boolean supportsStoredFunctionsUsingCallSyntax()        throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLException("Not yet implemented by SQLite JDBC driver"); }        
    public ResultSet getSchemas(String a, String b) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLException("Not yet implemented by SQLite JDBC driver"); }        
    public RowIdLifetime getRowIdLifetime()throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLException("Not yet implemented by SQLite JDBC driver"); }  
    public boolean isWrapperFor(Class<?> iface) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLException("Not yet implemented by SQLite JDBC driver"); }  
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> iface) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLException("Not yet implemented by SQLite JDBC driver"); }  
}
```